# Hadoop new API - Set OutputFormat

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to set the OutputFormat of my job to  MapFileOutputFormat using:

```
jobConf.setOutputFormat(MapFileOutputFormat.class);
```

I get this error: mapred.output.format.class is incompatible with new reduce API mode

I suppose I should use the set `setOutputFormatClass()` of the new Job class but the problem is that when I try to do this:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(MapFileOutputFormat.class);
```

it expects me to use this class: `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MapFileOutputFormat`.
In hadoop 1.0.X there is no such class. It only exists in earlier versions (e.g 0.x)

How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you copy it from the 0.x versions to 1.0?

Comment: First, it doesn't sound like a very natural solution. Second, technically speaking, I should first discover the jar it belongs to and replace the whole jar (or add that class to the corresponding 1.0.X jar in my distribution)

Comment: It's open source, it is the most natural solution you normally do. Just download the 0.x source, search for the java file and put it into your project. That's where it only needs to be, you don't have to recompile any code on your cluster or your distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has no decently easily implementable solution.

I gave up and used Sequence files which fit my requirements too.

Comment: how  to used Sequence files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output;
...
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, MapFileOutputFormat.class);
```